# How to address "WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object" and wait for a frame to be available using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, frameset

I have a rather complex webpage setup I need to test, containing nested frames.

In the actual problem the selenium code is loading new webpage contents containing a frame, which I want to switch to. In order to avoid any explicit waits, I tried the following code snippet:

```
self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 300).\
        until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'frame1')))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 300).\
        until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'frame2')))
```

However, this snippet always fails and results in the following error:

```
  ...
  File "/home/adietz/Projects/Venv/nosetests/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/home/adietz/Projects/Venv/nosetests/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 247, in __call__
    self.frame_locator))
  File "/home/adietz/Projects/Venv/nosetests/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 402, in _find_element
    raise e
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object
```

However, if I use a sleep in addition:

```
time.sleep(30)
self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 300).\
        until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'frame1')))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 300).\
        until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'frame2')))
```

selenium is able to find the frame inside the frame and switch to it. It looks like in the error case selenium switches to 'frame1' while 'frame2' is not yet loaded, but 'frame2' gets loaded in some other instance of 'frame1', or not recognized by selenium (maybe a bug?). So now selenium is inside some 'frame1' and for some reasons does not realize that the 'frame2' has been loaded.

The only way I can fix this (without using a long sleep) is by using this ugly piece of code:

```
    mustend = time.time() + 300
    while time.time() < mustend:
        try:
            self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
            self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame1"))
            self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame2"))               
            break
        except WebDriverException as e:
            self.log("Sleeping 1 sec")
            time.sleep(1)
    if time.time() > mustend:
        raise TimeoutException
```

So whenever I get a `WebDriverException` (dead object), I go to the top-level frame and try to switch to the inner frame - frame by frame.

Is there any other approach I can try?

**Additional information**

- The iframes are nested, i.e. 'frame2' is inside 'frame1'.

Comment: Can you add a piece of your html with frames?

Comment: @suit: That will not be possible...

Comment: I will try to copy parts of the html, but not sure how I can do that easily...

Answer (score 3):

Better approach is to make your own expected_condition.
For example:

```
class nested_frames_to_be_available_and_switch:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        """
        :param args: locators tuple of nested frames (BY.ID, "ID1"), (BY.ID, "ID2"), ...
        """
        self.locators = args

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            for locator in self.locators:
                driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(*locator))
        except WebDriverException:
            driver.switch_to_default_content()
            return False
        return True

WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(nested_frames_to_be_available_and_switch((By.ID, 'frame1'), (By.ID, 'frame1')))
```

But maybe there is no need for that.. To tell so I need to see your html DOM.

Comment: Its similar to my approach, but wrapped in some consistent naming. I like that...

Comment: @Alex, I have took another look at the EC.* classes and fixed my code

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object
```

...implies that there was an error while switching between `<iframes>`.

Some more information in terms of:

- The relevant *HTML*
- Presence of *Frameset*
- Presence of *Frames*
- Hierarchy of *Nested Frames*
- Sequence of *Frame Loading*
- Presence of *JavaScript* and *AJAX Calls* within the respective `<iframe>` tags

would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, at this point it is worth to mention that initially [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) always gets the focus on the **default_content**. Here are a few approaches to work with nested `<frames>` and `<framesets>`:

- If both *frame1* and *frame2* are at same level i.e. under the **Top Level Browsing Context** you need to:

  ```
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame1"))
  self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame2"))
  ```
- If *frame2* is nested within *frame1*, to switch from *frame1* to *frame2* you need to:

  ```
  self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame1"))
  //code
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame2"))
  ```
- If *frame2* and *frame3* is within *frame1* then, to switch from  *frame2* to *frame3* you need to:

  ```
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame2"))
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame1"))
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame3"))
  ```
- If *frame2* and *frame3* is within a *frameset23* which is within *frame1* then, to switch from  *frame2* to *frame3* you need to:

  ```
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame2"))
  #ignore presence of frameset23
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame1"))
  #ignore presence of frameset23
  self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frame3"))
  ```

---

### Better approach with proper WebDriverWait

While dealing with [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) and [frameset](/questions/tagged/frameset) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions):

```
frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()
```

As an example to switch from *Top Level Browsing Context* to an `<iframe>` an effective line of code will be:

- Using *frame* ID:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frameID")))
  ```
- Using *frame* NAME:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"frameNAME")))
  ```
- Using *frame* CLASS_NAME:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.frame_CLASS_NAME,"u_0_f")))
  ```
- Using *frame* CSS_SELECTOR:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame_CSS_SELECTOR")))
  ```
- Using *frame* XPATH:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"frame_XPATH")))
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)

Comment: Tried it all including `WebDriverWait`. With that I get the same error (i.e. see question where I use `WebDriverWait`...)

Comment: DebanjanB:  Do you know of some documentation/book which explains in depth all of the HTML DOM, Framesets, Frame loading, interaction with javascript, AJAX calls etc etc etc?