# Issue finding a string in scripts using xpath/selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm scanning a website to check if a certain script exists on the site. I have been successful in extracting this information from most sites but there are a few which is causing trouble for me eg. 247sports.com, where I'm unable to get this information the DOM looks like this

...

```
<iframe src='...'>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang..>
  <head>
  <iframe> ...</iframe>
  ...
  <script id="utag_81" src="https://js.agkn.com/prod/v0/tag.js?_rnd=0.6281110988358267" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async=""></script>
  ...
</iframe>
```

I'm using Firefox Webdriver to look for the "agkn" string in  src="https://js.agkn.com/prod..."

Python code:

```
x = Webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//iframe|//script|//img|//a)[contains(text(),'agkn') or contains(@src,'agkn') or contains(.,'agkn') or contains(@id,'utag_81') ]")
```

the length of x is always 0.

does the `<!DOCTYPE html>` have something to do with this?.

Comment: You need to switch to the desired frame to retrieve the contents from the `<script>` tag. Follow the discussion [How to properly wait for a frame to be available in python-selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811895/how-to-properly-wait-for-a-frame-to-be-available-in-python-selenium/47814675#47814675)  and [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)for proper frame handling

Answer (score 0):

if you have iframes in your code, you need to switch to that iframe first and get element from that level.

Sample code:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/img")
```

Comment: for some reason switch_to_frame( Name/ID) kept giving me issues  so I used the switch_to.frame(i) and it worked like a charm

Comment: my mistake. correct syntax is switch_to.frame(i) as you mentioned. edited post as well.