# Switching back to parent frame after it's no longer in DOM in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

I have the following page

```
<body>
  <iframe id="outer_frame">
    <iframe id="search_button_frame">
      <button id="search_button"></button>
    </iframe>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

Now after I click on the `search_button` the two `frames outer_frame` and `search_button_frame` are no longer in DOM and instead the page becomes like this

```
<body>
  <iframe id="form_frame">
    ...
  </iframe>
</body>
```

I'm trying to go to the `search_button` then get out of the frames into the main page, and then switching to the `form_frame` using this:

```
outer_frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="outer_frame"]')
browser.switch_to.frame(outer_frame)

search_button_frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_button_frame"]')
browser.switch_to.frame(search_button_frame)

search_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_button"]')
search_button.click()

browser.switch_to_default_content()

form_frame = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_frame"]')
browser.switch_to.frame(form_frame)
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Una
ble to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="form_frame"]"}
```

does this mean I'm not positioned in the right frame?

Comment: IMO, you are doing absolutely fine. add some wait before  switching to form_frame,  and replace your all xpath with id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question and the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) structure post clicking on the `search_button` you need to *switch* to the `default_content()` first and then switch to the next desired `<iframe>` using *WebDriverWait* as follows:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"form_frame")))
```

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)
- [How to properly wait for a frame to be available in python-selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811895/how-to-properly-wait-for-a-frame-to-be-available-in-python-selenium/47814675#47814675)

Comment: Thank you! it worked! however I think it should be `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"form_frame")))` because doing it with only one parantheses gives the following error TypeError:  `__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Answer (score 1):

As per the standard procedure: first, save the parent handle of the browser.
String handle = driver.getwindowhandle();

Then try to switch into a frame with the wait so that driver can wait for some time if it is not present now in DOM.
After completing the work on the frame then again switch to parentWindow (default window).
The same procedure can apply to every frame which would always work perfectly.