# WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In a rather complex python-selenium test script (which is not accessible from the outside, so I cannot provide an example), I have the following line waiting for an element to become visible:

```
WebDriverWait(basedriver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"clb-iframe-workspace")))
elem = WebDriverWait(basedriver, 20).\
           until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "Feature extraction")]')))
```

In most cases there is no problem and the web driver finds the element in question. But sometimes (about 1 in 10 cases) I get the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object
```

And strangely that happens right away! Selenium does not even bother to wait the 20 seconds I want selenium to wait by using `WebDriverWait`!

Maybe the `iframe` switch could have something to do with it? 
I also tried to make a screenshot just before the failing line - I get a blank white screen in both cases. So how to debug this any further myself? And why does the `WebDriverWait` not wait...?

Addendum

- I have implemented the suggestion from DebanjanB, but I still get the same error at a level of 5%.
- If I use a slower internet connection, the error takes place *almost all the time*!
- When I insert code to take screenshots and write out the page source (which takes some time to do), the error rate decreases again.

So I would say its definitive a timing issue, combined with a **bug** in selenium...

Comment: Why not google this error? Someone says adding `switch_to_default_content()` before will work.

Comment: I need to switch to an iframe just before I look for this element, so switching back to the default content is completely wrong!

Comment: Claim down. There are many different situations. For example, you forget to switch back from an iframe. Or the iframe is reloaded before you access the elements. Basically, you are not in the right content.

Comment: But why does it work 90% of the times, and sometimes it does not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811895/how-to-properly-wait-for-a-frame-to-be-available-in-python-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *best practices* switching to an `<iframe>` must be implemented inducing *WebDriverwait* with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause [frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it).

---

### class frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(object)

`class frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(object)` is the expectation for checking whether the given frame is available to switch to.  If the frame is available it switches the given driver to the specified frame.

---

So you need to replace the lines:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(basedriver, 20).\
        until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'clb-iframe-workspace')))
basedriver.switch_to_frame(elem)
```

as:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"clb-iframe-workspace")))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion I will try it. However, where can I find such 'best practices'? Or can you suggest a dicument/book which explains all the inner details of selenium and the webdriver in greatest technical details, so I can learn and understand all about  the htlm dom, frames, driver, geckodriver etc etc?

Comment: The error did reappear. Your suggestion did not help to fix my problem. 

But I still would be greatful if you can provide a really good in-depth and detailed technical documentation (which, for examples, explains EACH possible selenium/webdriver error in great detail. ...)

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. The frame changes inbetween. A new frame is being loaded. I have to check the title...

Comment: @Alex As you asked, I am in the process of preparing a detailed technical documentation on frame handling