# Selenium (Python) >> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, automated-tests

I've been trying to enter to an iframe and write text in a search bar ( tag) in Safari:

I can't post the html because it's huge and it isn't mine but this is the iframe code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="contentIFrame0" name="contentIFrame0" title="Área de contenido" style="border: 0px none; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; visibility: visible; display: block;"> (...Content of the iframe...) </iframe>
```

Here is python code:

```
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="contentIFrame0"]')))
chk_elem = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="2crmGrid_findCriteria"]')))
act = ActionChains(driver)
act.move_to_element(chk_elem)
act.send_keys('Search input', Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

but I always get this Exception: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message:".

I've been watching some tutorials and even reading the official documentation and I guess my code is Ok. Why it isn't working?

PD:
There aren't another iframe before the iframe that I posted and XPATHs are well written. I don't know if it is relevant but we are talking about a web site of dynamics services from microsoft, just in case.

Comment: Either there isn't a frame with id `contentIFrame0` or its inside another frame and you need to switch to it first. Post the relevant html.

Comment: Hey!!! I edited the question, I can't get the full html code from my browser but I checked again if there is another iframe before my target iframe and the XPATH and all is right but the problem persists.

Comment: `I can't get the full html code from my browser` what is stopping you from doing that unless it is security concern.

Comment: Actually is all about security reasons of the institution. Could it be about the iframe is loading too slow or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException
```

...implies that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance was unable to locate the `<iframe>` element.

---

You have adapted the right approach. Ideally, to locate an [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) set as [frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it).

However, there can be numerous reasons behind seeing this error and some of the reasons and solutions are as follows:

- The desired *iframe* may be a nested *iframe* within it's parent *iframe*. In those cases you have to induce *WebDriverWait* first to switch to the *parent iframe* and then to the *child iframe* as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"parent_iframe_xpath")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"child_iframe_xpath")))
  ```
- If you are switching between two sibling *iframes* then you first need to switch back to the `default_content` first and then switch to the sibling iframe as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"sibling_iframe_A")))
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"sibling_iframe_B")))
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to address “WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object” and wait for a frame to be available using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811895/how-to-address-webdriverexception-message-typeerror-cant-access-dead-object/47814675#47814675)

- At times multiple *iframes* can have similar values for same attributes. In those cases, you may need to construct [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which identifies the `<iframe>` element uniquely using the `src` attribute as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id="iframe_id and @src='iframe_src'"]")))
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

- Finally, you need to ensure that the binary versions are compatible and you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

  - [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)
  - [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)
  - [What is the correct IEDriverServer version to use with IE 11 through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285722/what-is-the-correct-iedriverserver-version-to-use-with-ie-11-through-selenium/55286348#55286348)
- The *timeout* configured for *WebDriverWait* may be too less and in that case you need to increase the timeout as follows;:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"parent_iframe_xpath")))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of reference discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was pretty useful to learn more good practices with selenium!!! I'll mark it right. Actually I already solved the problem, the problem was iframe loading slowly and selenium driver catch the iframe but it can't get elements inside it because the element hasn't load yet.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB - I had similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750498/select-frame-fails-with-no-frame-to-select-in-robotframework but the problem I see is that in the source I see this msg Oops! Your browser is not compatible with iframes, is it something common when the browser opens in automation mode? I am still not able to figure out the problem though :(