# Select frame fails with no frame to select in robotframework

Tags: selenium, iframe, automation, robotframework

I am trying to test iframe with robotframework and when using the Select Frame keyword with  it always throws the error as,

```
NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

When tried to print the source code to check if the iframe is visible I see the below,

```
    <iframe name="frame-view" title="frame-view" width="100%" height="100%" src=<url> frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox">
    Oops! Your browser is not compatible with iframes
    </iframe>
```

Is it the browser which spawns is blocked to access the iframe and hence the keyword to select even fails? Just assuming this now, would be great if someone can give insight on this to fix. Thanks.

Comment: What locator are you using when trying to select the frame?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the reply. Am using the frame name so like, Select Frame frame-view

Comment: Have you checked if this iframe is wrapped in another frame/frames?

Comment: Have you verified there isn't anything else on that page with the same name?

Comment: @supputuri no, it's not wrapped to another frame its direct from the root.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes there is different control like button with the same, will that affect the flow? cause Select Frame should ideally select which of <iframe>?

Comment: Ideally other button element with same `name` attribute value should not impact `Select Frame` as that method (command) is specific to frames and internally it will filter the elements based on the frames and provided attribute value.

Comment: @supputuri is this msg in source ok? Oops! Your browser is not compatible with iframes

Comment: Do you seethe message, but still see the iframe in the source?